# Convert Pandas Series to Dictionary Without Index

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I need to convert Pandas Series to a Dictionary, without Index (like pandas.DataFrame.to_dict('r')) - code is below:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(index_column)
for key, val in tqdm(grouped):
    json_dict[key] = val.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(), axis=1).to_dict()
```

Currently, I get output like so:

```
{
   "15717":{
      "col1":1.61,
      "col2":1.53,
      "col3":1.0
   },
   "15718":{
      "col1":10.97,
      "col2":5.79,
      "col3":2.0
   },
   "15719":{
      "col1":15.38,
      "col2":12.81,
      "col3":1.0
   }
}
```

but i need output like:

```
[
   {
      "col1":1.61,
      "col2":1.53,
      "col3":1.0
   },
   {
      "col1":10.97,
      "col2":5.79,
      "col3":2.0
   },
   {
      "col1":15.38,
      "col2":12.81,
      "col3":1.0
   }
]
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Here is the original dataframe:

```
        col1   col2 col3
2751    5.46    1.0 1.11
2752    16.47   0.0 6.54
2753    26.51   0.0 18.25
2754    31.04   1.0 28.95
2755    36.45   0.0 32.91
```

Comment: Could you please add the original dataframe, so one could reproduce your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways of doing that:

```
[v for _, v in df.to_dict(orient="index").items()]
```

Another one:

```
df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

The output, either way, is:

```
[{'col1': 1.61, 'col2': 1.53, 'col3': 1.0},
 {'col1': 10.97, 'col2': 5.79, 'col3': 2.0},
 {'col1': 15.38, 'col2': 12.81, 'col3': 1.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df.T.to_dict('r')
```

Output:

```
[{'col1': 1.61, 'col2': 1.53, 'col3': 1.0},
 {'col1': 10.97, 'col2': 5.79, 'col3': 2.0},
 {'col1': 15.38, 'col2': 12.81, 'col3': 1.0}]
```